# Displaying symbology only for largest part of polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, display, multipart, multi-polygon

In QGIS 3.22.0 (Bialowieza) I have a polygon *layer* of municipalities in Germany. Some municipalities consist of more than one polygon. I have duplicated the layer in order to make a categorization of a value within the layer. The categorization is displayed as a point-symbol.

My problem is that the municipalities with more than one polygon also show more than one point-symbol (attached image). How can I reduce the number of points and have the point only displayed in the largest polygon. (The municipality of [Konstanz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konstanz) consists of three polygons.)

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by *"[schon](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/schon#German)"*? *"show"*? *"already has"*? Or something else?

Comment: oh, thank you! Its supposed to be "show".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried to change symbol settings?

Layer Properties > Symbology > Symbol (arrow down) > Configure Symbol > Symbol layer type set on Centroid Fill.

At this point you should uncheck "Draw markers on every part of multi-part features".

[image]

Comment: This only works for multipart geometries, not for single parts. OP mentions that some municipalities consist "of more than one polygon".

Comment: Thank you! I knew there was a setting, just couldnt find it!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to create a marker only on the largest polygon of those with the same value for attribute `name`, use the Geometry generator with this expression:

```
if (
    area ($geometry) = 
        array_max (
            array_agg (
                area($geometry), 
                group_by:=name  --change this for the attribute field name
            )
        ),
    centroid ($geometry),
    ''
)
```

[image]

Comment: This didnt work for my case because i had already categorized the attributes. There was no need for generating geometries (it probably could've worked, but I'm still not that professional with expressions). Thanks for your help